# Excel file corrupt when copied from src to target in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a strange issue with eclipse. When I put a .xls file in the `src/test/resources` path it is copied by eclipse to the `target` path.

However, the file in the target path is not the same anymore. I cannot open it in MS Excel anymore and when I compare the two files, I see some binary differences. How can this happen?

PS: my eclipse environment is generated with maven.

Comment: Have you tried to exclude ressource from filtering ? http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Thanks to the above answers we found out how to deal with the problem:

```
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <configuration>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
          <nonFilteredFileExtension>xls</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I didn't know these options :)

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue, and it was cause by the Maven resources plugin which filtered and altered my Excel files.

To prevent this to happen, add something like this (see the [Maven doc](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html)) :

```
<build>               
       <resources>
           <resource>
               <filtering>true</filtering>
               <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
               <excludes>
                   <exclude>**/*.xls</exclude>
               </excludes>
         </resource>
...
```

UPDATE : Copy in resources, but don't filter

```
<resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.xls</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.xls</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
```

Comment: Ant build script have similar issues, when you apply a filter it has to read the file, this assumes you are using a text file and the files will be copied as text and not as bytes resulting in corruption

Comment: with this snippet the xls file will not be copied. However, we need the file, but not corrupted

Comment: @nico_ekito - Please would you clarify your answer, its unclear what has been updated, and what is the actual answer.  thanks.

Comment: I think you have the include and exclude mixed up. The `filtering=true` resource should _exclude_ excel files, and the `filtering=false` resource should _include_ excel files.

Comment: The same concept applies to `maven-assembly-plugin`. Excel files should be in a separate `fileSet` tag. Worked for me.

Comment: This saved my day!