# File corrupted after antrun

Tags: maven, filtering, pom.xml, maven-antrun-plugin

I'm having a problem with my pom file, I need filtering option to be on, but I want to exclude this option on mp3 files which are placed in resource folder. Right now after antrun command files are corrupted and unplayable. I've done something like this:

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources/sounds</directory>
    <excludes>
       <exclude>**/*.mp3</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

any ideas?

Comment: If you know that is caused by the antrun how should we guess what's wrong based on a pom snippet?

Comment: well, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024185/excel-file-corrupt-when-copied-from-src-to-target-in-eclipse-ide the community somehow managed to help...

Comment: If your question is answered just close the question.

Comment: when it will be answered I sure will close it