# Maven Resource Filtering Breaking Downloads

Tags: maven, properties, resources, profiles

I have a Maven/Java application. Part of the application allows you to download some documents. Here is the project setup.

```
+src
    +main
        +resources
            +downloads
                MyDocument.docx
            jdbc.properties
pom.xml
```

The downloads work correctly when `jdbc.properties` has the hardcoded values inside them. However, I am trying to update the application to use Maven profiles and specify the different database connections for the different environments. I manage to get it to work with the following in `pom.xml`.

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

However, even though the `jdbc.properties` file gets correctly populated with the correct environment database information, the download feature stopped working. The file will be downloaded, but when you try to open it, it says `The file MyDocument.docx cannot be opened because there are problems with the contents.`.

I tried changing the `<directory>` to `src/main/resources/*.properties` and adding an additional `<resource>` where I turn the `<filtering>` to false for `src/main/resources/downloads`. But neither approach worked.  How can I prevent the Maven filtering from corrupting the files?

FYI - I looked inside the WAR and the documents cannot be opened from there either (they are already corrupt).

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: Better solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10025058/516167

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <configuration>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
      <nonFilteredFileExtension>xls</nonFilteredFileExtension>
    </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

---

You should exclude files like *MyDocument.docx* (*.docs) from filtering.

```
<build>
   <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resouces</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.docx</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

or define alternate directory for downloads like:

```
<build>
   <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/downloads</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Comment: When I do the first one, there is a `NullPointerException` on my `InputStream` for the download. It was populated as `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/downloads/MyDocument.docx");`.

Comment: With the second option, the files are still being reported as corrupt.

Comment: I also tried adding `<filtering>false</filtering>` to the 2nd option. And also reordering the `<resource>` tags, but no luck. Always saying it's corrupt.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024185/excel-file-corrupt-when-copied-from-src-to-target-in-eclipse-ide

Comment: Using the nonFilteredFileExtensions suggestion above worked for me.