# drools could not open decision table from XLS file

Tags: apache-poi, drools, kie

I could create a fresh spring boot project and successfully run all rules getting from an excel file by following this: http://www.baeldung.com/drools-excel
however If I just add same maven dependencies in my existing spring boot project, I can only use rules in CSV format. if I use .xls, I get error org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NotOLE2FileException: Invalid header signature; read 0xE011BDBFEFBDBFEF, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document

Not sure what am I missing here but I have tried a lot from past 8 hours but no luck

Can anybody suggest please?

Comment: CSV != XLS, so it's hardly surprising that code that only deals with XLS is refusing your CSV file...

Comment: My question is different!

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this after I accidentally tried to open rules excel file on *target* folder. It was corrupt. It was a maven setup issue. I had to waste a day on this crap issue. this post: [Excel file corrupt when copied from src to target in Eclipse IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024185/excel-file-corrupt-when-copied-from-src-to-target-in-eclipse-ide)
helped me to resolve my issue