# How to construct the response body for InputStream which has an Excel sheet file?

Tags: java, excel, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am writing a get API for getting excel sheet file stored in src/main/resources.

The InputStream has the content of excel file (xlsm format). But the response is having corrupted data.

```
@GetMapping("/downloadTemplate")
public ResponseEntity<?> downloadTemplate() throws IOException {
    String fn = "filename";

    try {
        File file = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fn).getFile());
        InputStreamSource iss = new FileSystemResource(file);

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename= SimpleStandardTemplate.xlsm")
                .body(IOUtils.toByteArray(iss.getInputStream()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("An error occurred while trying to downloadTemplate: {}", e);
        throw new ApiException(ApiErrorCode.DEFAULT_410, "Error while downloading");
    }
}
```

Seems like this line has a problem "body(IOUtils.toByteArray(iss.getInputStream()));" . If yet any alternate way? Else what could be the issue?

Edit: I think the issue is with content length.

Comment: Do you have the exact error message ?

Comment: Set content type of the response `response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxml");`

Comment: Thanks for the answers. This solved my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024185/excel-file-corrupt-when-copied-from-src-to-target-in-eclipse-ide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer fixed the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10025058/10411625)

Added this plugin to the pom.

```
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <configuration>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
           <nonFilteredFileExtension>xls</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, tested with spring-boot `1.5.6`

```
@GetMapping("/export")
  public ResponseEntity<Resource> download() throws IOException {
    String fileName ="<file-path>";
    Resource resource = new FileSystemResource(fileName);
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE))
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + resource.getFilename() + "\"")
        .body(resource);
  }
```

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: cannot be resolved in the file system for checking its content length

Comment: Have you tried by giving full file path? `String fileName ="<file-path>";` Give the complete file path here with file name. if working modify with class path resource.

Answer (score 0):

I think your MIME type is wrong, [Refer this for excel Mime types](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsofficedeveloper/2008/05/08/office-2007-file-format-mime-types-for-http-content-streaming-2/), I have change the way you send the file using `Spring's` `FileSystemResource`

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/downloadTemplate", produces = "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12")
public FileSystemResource downloadTemplate(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    String fn = "filename";
    File file = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fn).getFile()); 
    response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename= SimpleStandardTemplate.xlsm");
    return new FileSystemResource(file); // You could directly pass the absolute path of the file
}
```

Comment: response.setHeader(); Where is response object? I am getting error in that line of your code.

Comment: Tried without setting response.setHeader(), it did'nt work and I am getting same issue. Getting response but the file gets corrupted

Comment: @MohammedShirhaan, I did not add `HttpServletResponse response` in controller parameter, now check and another thing are you able to open the file ?

Comment: still having the same issue. I getting a response like `PK!����[Content_Types].xml �(��VKo�0�#�"_Q�m�B�큖#Tj��z�Ib6~�v��g�dK)٤Ѯ����1c{��V�I�K�3rAW$-L.u����_ҏ$���FCF��������ނO�}F��'Ƽ�@qO��#�q�|u%�\�x` . But the if I save the response as an excel file, the file is corrupted.

Comment: I am checking the response of the api using Insomnia. The above response is how it looks like  and it goes on. In Insomnia there is an option to save the response as a file.

Comment: @MohammedShirhaan I am facing the same problem, I am getting the downloadable file but I am also getting the garbage values as mentioned above. Do you have the solution?

Comment: @Fakipo yes I had got the solution. I have added the reference and the answer to this question now. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

One potential problem is that your original file is not xlsm file. For example, Excel doesn't allow you to open a normal xlsx file under macro enabled mode. Please double check.

Comment: I have checked. It is xlsm file.

Comment: Please check content-length in response header. If it is incorrect, set real content-length in your response header. IOUtils should work.

Comment: How to set real content-length in response header? Please tell me?

Comment: .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, nnn)  //nnn is the size of file.

Comment: `The method header(String, String...) in the type ResponseEntity.HeadersBuilder<ResponseEntity.BodyBuilder> is not applicable for the arguments (String, long)`

Comment: java.lang.Long.toString(long)