# Invalid header signature when read any xls file

Tags: java, apache-poi, xls

When I try to read xls file using the code below, I always get error:
org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NotOLE2FileException: Invalid header signature; read 0x65572D2D2D2D2D2D, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document.

This is my code:

```
public Result<List<IDto>> ReadExcelClassInfo2003(File file,
            Timestamp createTime, Timestamp updateTime, BigDecimal createBy,
            BigDecimal updateBy) {

        Result<List<IDto>> resultData = new Result<List<IDto>>();
        Integer numInsertSuccess = 0;

        if (file == null) {
            resultData.setErrorCode(ErrorCode.ERROR_FORMAT);
            return resultData;
        }
        try {

            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
            POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(is);
            Integer classType = ClassTypeEnum.CLASSROOM.getValue();
            Integer maxCol = ExcelConstant.MAX_COLUMN_CLASSROOM_INFO;

            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
            HSSFSheet sheetClassInfo = workbook
                    .getSheetAt(0);

            if (sheetClassInfo == null) {
                resultData.setErrorCode(ErrorCode.ERROR_FORMAT);
                return resultData;
            }

            //Some code to get data from excel file here.


            is.close();
            workbook.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            resultData.setErrorCode(ErrorCode.ERROR_FORMAT);
            return resultData;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            resultData.setErrorCode(ErrorCode.ERROR_FORMAT);
            return resultData;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            resultData.setErrorCode(ErrorCode.ERROR_FORMAT);
            return resultData;
        }

        if (numInsertSuccess == 0) {
            resultData.setErrorCode(ErrorCode.CLASS_DATA_INVALID);
            return resultData;
        }

        resultData.setErrorCode(ErrorCode.IMPORT_SUCCESS);
        resultData.setMessage(numInsertSuccess.toString());

        return resultData;
    }
```

My controller code :

```
@POST
    @Path("class/import")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @RolesAllowed(Role.TRAINING_ADMIN)
//  public Response importClass(@FormParam("file") File file) {
    public Response importClass(@Multipart("file") File file) {
        LOGGER.info("Received PUT import class: file=" + file.length());
        if (checkTokenAndRole(new int[] {1, 11}).getStatus() != Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode()) {           
            return LoginError(checkToken().getStatus());                
        } else {
            String token = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
            String fileExtension = request.getHeader("FileExtension");
            return ClassService.getInstance().importClass(file, fileExtension,
                    token);
        }
    }
```

And the method are call by controller :

```
public Response importClass(File file, String fileExtension, String token) {
        Result<List<IDto>> result = new Result<List<IDto>>();
        try {

            ErrorDTO errorDto = new ErrorDTO();
            String data = "";

            double bytes = file.length();
            double kilobytes = (bytes / 1024);
            double megabytes = (kilobytes / 1024);
            if (megabytes > ExcelConstant.MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
                errorDto.setErrorCode(ErrorCode.ERROR_FORMAT);
                data = Utility.toJSONString(errorDto);

                return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                        .entity(data).build();
            }

            Timestamp createTime = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
            Timestamp updateTime = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
            BigDecimal createBy = null;
            BigDecimal updateBy = null;

            Result<UserInfoDTO> userInfo = DaoManager.getUserInfoDao()
                    .getUserInfoByToken(token);
            if (userInfo.getData() != null) {
                createBy = userInfo.getData().getId();
                updateBy = userInfo.getData().getId();
            }

            result = DaoManager.getClassDao().importClass(file, fileExtension,
                    createTime, updateTime, createBy, updateBy);

            int errorCode = result.getErrorCode();
            String message = result.getMessage();


            errorDto = new ErrorDTO();
            errorDto.setErrorCode(errorCode);
            errorDto.setMessage(message);
            data = Utility.toJSONString(errorDto);

            // release memory
            userInfo = null;
            return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                    .entity(data).build();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
            result.setStatus(Constant.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            result.setErrorCode(ErrorCode.IMPORT_ERROR);

            return super.responseData(result);
        }

    }
```

```
public Result<List<IDto>> importClass(File file, String fileExtension,
            Timestamp createTime, Timestamp updateTime, BigDecimal createBy,
            BigDecimal updateBy) throws IOException {

        return ExportExcelService.getInstance().ReadExcelClassInfo2003(file,
                fileExtension, createTime, updateTime, createBy, updateBy);
    }
```

I debuged and found the process always check new POIFSFileSystem and throw exception with error above. I tested with all xls file I have and have same error.
Any can help me resolve this problem, and what the header 0x65572D2D2D2D2D2D ?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is `File file` coming from?

Comment: I choose any file .xls from my computer and get same issue

Comment: It's not a regular Microsoft Excel file! If you open it with Excel (which ignores incorrect file endings) and do a save-as, what filetype is shown by default?

Comment: @Gagravarr I tried to do it but this issue occured

Comment: Please show how `File file` gets instantiated. Where is the file resource stored? Is it possible that `Maven` is envolved and "filters" the `*.xls` file? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024185/excel-file-corrupt-when-copied-from-src-to-target-in-eclipse-ide.

Comment: this is a method in my web app, I browse an any .xls file from computer, and the file are save in target path is the same as describe in link you gave. But I do not use Maven project, my project is javaEE and using POIFSFileSystem.class in web app library

Comment: All I can tell you is that something corrupts your `*.xls` files **before** `InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file); POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(is);` runs. As you dont want showing how `File file` gets instantiated and how the `*.xls` files are coming into their locations, no further help is possible.

Comment: @AxelRichter Sorry about my understanding, I will give controller, service and DAO code in my answer below

Comment: I investigated and realized I am using Apache POI 3.13 for java 1.8, the problem occured when I changed server from using java 1.6 to java 1.8. Is there any wrong when I use current Apache POI version for java 1.8?

Comment: Version `3.13` is rather old and far away from current version. Current version is [apache poi 4.1.2](https://poi.apache.org/download.html#POI-4.1.2). But I doubt this will be the reason. The reason is that your `File file` is corrupt.

Comment: @AxelRichter So as your answer, root cause maybe the Content-Transfer-Encoding is BASE64 because I encoded file from multipart/form-data? And what is difference between encoded file using Multipath and FormParam anonation?

Comment: I am not a `Java EE` expert but I've never seen `@Multipart("file") File file` in context of a method which consumes `multipart/form-data`. There is a specilal `MultipartFile` class which most times is used. So I would suggest at first checking whether this works correctly. Let your controller method store the file somewhere and then check whether this is a proper `Excel` file. Is `Excel` able opening that stored file without problems?

Comment: @AxelRichter Thanks for your support, I reliazed after updating from WAS8.5 to WAS9.0, JAX-RS is also updated from 1.1 to 2.0. Library change and cannot use Formparam anonation for file .xls and .xlsx anymore. So I changed method from use FormParam anonation to use IMultiPartBody, change IMultipartBody to byte array and use it for read file .xls and .xlsx with Apache Poi.