# Illegal URL-encoded characters when using @FormParam to upload file

Tags: java, websphere, java-ee-6

I have controller code below

```
@POST
    @Path("class/import")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @RolesAllowed(Role.TRAINING_ADMIN)
    public Response importClass(@FormParam("file") File file) {
        LOGGER.info("Received PUT import class: file=" + file.length());
        if (checkTokenAndRole(new int[] {1, 11}).getStatus() != Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode()) {           
            return LoginError(checkToken().getStatus());                
        } else {
            String token = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
            String fileExtension = request.getHeader("FileExtension");
            return ClassService.getInstance().importClass(file, fileExtension,
                    token);
        }
    }
```

This code run normally in enviroment java 6, JPA 2.0, Websphere Application Server 8.5. But when I upgraded enviroment using java 8, JPA 2.1 and Websphere Application Server 9.0, this code gave error:

```
Illegal URL-encoded characters, make sure that no @FormParam and @Multipart annotations are mixed up
```

I tried changing @FormParam to @Multipart, the code run but I cannot upload excel file because Apache Poi cannot read encoded file ( the Content-Transfer-Encoding is BASE64 with @Multipart).
So anyone help me give the solution to use @FormParam normally?
Thanks.

Comment: You probably should tag that question better. As said in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61604995/invalid-header-signature-when-read-any-xls-file, I am neither a `Java EE` nor a `Websphere` expert. But you do not reach those experts with a question only tagged `java`.

Comment: So... the WAS upgrade will have switched the JAX-RS implementation from Apache Wink to Apache CXF. I wonder if searching with those details might be helpful

Comment: Also, can you describe how the file is being submitted? Is it a plain browser web form?

Comment: Thanks for support of everyone, I reliazed after updating from WAS8.5 to WAS9.0, JAX-RS is also updated from 1.1 to 2.0. Library change and cannot use Formparam anonation for file .xls and .xlsx anymore. So I changed method from use FormParam anonation to use IMultiPartBody, change IMultipartBody to byte array and use it for read file .xls and .xlsx with Apache Poi.